# Adapter pattern in use and inheritance for a simple DB connection

Tags: php, database, design-patterns

I have a little problem trying to understand how my current database connection class was designed as an Adaptor. It provides a connect method which will invoke the parent's connect method which is PEAR's MDB2

```
require_once(MDB2....)

class Connection
{
   //new/overloading methods that call parents'methods   
}
```

To the basic definition of what adapter pattern is, I take it that Connection is one, but that makes me wonder the differences possible between Inheritance and Adapter in use ?

Any explanation is appreciated, thank you.

**Update**

What i can't figure out is if I redesign the class as

```
class Connection extends MDB2 //for example
{
    // my new methods
    // along with other overloading methods
}
```

Is my Connection still considered an Adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

> What i can't figure out is if I redesign the class as `...` is my Connection still considered an Adapter?

From what I understand, an adapter is used to allow objects not normally designed to work together still have the ability to operate seamlessly. For example:

```
class TwoProngOutlet
{
   public function connect($cord)
   {
      // Plug $cord into two prong outlet
   }
}

class ThreeProngOutlet
{ 
   public function connect($cord)
   {
      // Plug $cord into three prong outlet
   }
}

class OutletAdapter
{
   public function getOutlet($cord)
   {
      if($cord->prongs == 2)
      { 
         return new TwoProngOutlet($cord);
      }
      else if($cord->prongs == 3)
      {
         return new ThreeProngOutlet($cord);
      }
   }
}

$adapter = new OutletAdapter;
$cord = new TwoProngCord;

// Adapt outlet to meet cord type
$outlet = $adapter->getOutlet($cord);

// Plug it in without having to know what type of outlet we are using
$outlet->connect($cord);
```

Comment: I do not think this is a good example of Adapter pattern. From its own definition: "Adapter pattern is a design pattern that translates one interface for a class into a compatible interface". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern